# Cannot plot map on ArcGIS python API?

Tags: arcgis-python-api

I do not have ArcGIS desktop. And I have installed the ArcGIS Python API.

And I tried the following:

```
import arcgis
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.mapping import WebMap
gis = GIS()
map1 = gis.map('Paris') # Passing a place name to the constructor
                        # will initialize the extent of the map.
map1
```

No map displayed.

Why is that?

Comment: I dont know the arcgis-python-api but it looks like 'Paris' is just a string, like 'asdadas'. Shouldnt it be a variable or something else? Or `arcgis_online.map("Paris")`? (https://developers.arcgis.com/python/sample-notebooks/creating-hurricane-tracks-using-geoanalytics/)

Comment: some said I need to use python -m arcgis.install to enable the map widget. But I don't know how to do that in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/47694180/820534

Comment: Are you working with Anaconda or ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Anaconda. I dont have ArcGIS Pro